# translate ng-options values in select combobox after i switch the language?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, angular-translate

i'm trying to change the select combo-box values after switching language in JHIPSTER,
does anyone already done this ?! thanks in advance

```
<select   ng-model="ville.name" ng-options="ville.name as ville.name for ville in villes" name="ville.name" class="form-control" >
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change

`<select ng-model="ville.name" ng-options="ville.name as ville.name for ville in villes" name="ville.name" class="form-control" >`

into

`<select ng-model="ville.name" ng-options="ville.name as ville.name | translate for ville in villes" name="ville.name" class="form-control" >`

hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the value of `$scope.villes` and it would update automatically.

Comment: i did this but i dont know where to put the translation:         $scope.$watch('villes',function(){
         $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
                 angular.forEach($scope.villes, function(ville) {
                  ville.name = $translate(ville.name);
               
               });
             }); 
         }